# Are Hibernate filters only applied after the data has been loaded from db?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, filter

I've found some contradicting information on the net. Does anyone know whether Hibernate filters affect the generated sql, or is it just filtering the data as it's read from the database?

Comment: Remember that filters will only be applied when using the TypedQuery interface, so 'em.find(entityClass, primaryKey)' will not have the filter applied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate filters **affect the where clause** of the generated SQL.

The [Introduction to Hibernate Filters](http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-hibernate-filters) is a nice article on filters and provides a demo application allowing to play with them.

Answer (score 2):

If you enable SQL in Hibernate using `show_sql"(+"format_sql")`,
and execute query with enabled filter, you will see the result.

For example:

```
select
    item0_.ID as ID0_     
from
    ITEMS item0_ 
where
    item0_.deleted = 'FALSE' <-- here is filtering
```